# Running Talend child jobs through a parent job

Tags: talend

I want to develop a Talend job parent job which will read a file. This file will have all the child job names.
So the parent job when run must go through each entry in the file (ie each child job name) and execute the child job.
Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: What is the format of your input file? Can we have an example of your input file?

Comment: The input file can be a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tRunJob](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521FR/19.1+tRunJob) dynamic job feature, I executed 3 sub jobs called a, b and c, and the order is specified in the file, see below :

[image]

First block is to load your file into context, you can use a properties file or delimited file.

I used properties file with this content :

```
jobs=a;c;b;a
```

You have to add a string typed context variable named `jobs` to put the propertie value into.

Now, our job list is stored in a context variable, we need to iterate through them using [tJavaFlex](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/5.4+tJavaFlex) and update a context variable called `currentjob`:

[image]

And finally, this is how to set tRunJob component:

[image]

Here you specify jobs to be executed, but the execution order is specified by the file !

Comment: Are there schemas to be edited anywhere? and any context parameters to be filled? I am getting the error "job cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: u need 2 context variables, `jobs` which will have all jobs names in one string that comes from the file, and `currentjob` is the job to be executed in each iteration.

Comment: How can I create these context variables? I am new to talend, so I have no idea.

Comment: see here : [define context var](https://help.talend.com//pages/viewpage.action?pageId=261829429#Raa64916)

Comment: What will be the values that I must be giving to the two context variables jobs and currentjob?

Comment: just define the variables with string type, no need to give an default value.

Comment: No values required?

Comment: I have created the variables with no values, however I get the below error now

Exception in component tRunJob_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: The child job named  is not in the job list.
 at local_project.parent_0_1.Parent.tJavaFlex_1Process(Parent.java:1187)
 at local_project.parent_0_1.Parent.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(Parent.java:808)
 at local_project.parent_0_1.Parent.runJobInTOS(Parent.java:1572)
 at local_project.parent_0_1.Parent.main(Parent.java:1420)

Comment: in the tRunJob component you have to select all required jobs, see picture in my answer

Comment: I have selected all the required jobs. I still get this error. I think its something related to the context variables. Should I create the variables jobs and currentjob in the "Contexts" tab of the job? Also if I give empty values to it, it doesn't work. 
Please help!

Comment: Right now I get the error "key cannot be resolved or is not a field". Also I get the below errors in the trunjob
Parameter(context) is empty but is required
Parameter(job) is empty but is required.

Comment: @Harshi Please make as you see in the picture, check the `use dynamic job` parameter, put `context.currentjob` incontext job, and in fornt of the label job, select all jobs. See last picture its clear.

Comment: @Harshi You may changed or deleted the value of the context parameter, please be sure that its contain `Default`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following scenario

[image]

This is the sample job which I tried out.

I have assumed your input from CSV file and the input file contain three job name which are

```
ChildJob1
ChildJob2
ChildJob3
```

I am getting the jobname and assigning it to a context variable like below

[image]

Then that context variable is used in `tRunJob` component.

[image]

Each child job has a single `tjava` component which displays the jobname

[image]

Hope this may help you out.

Comment: I got the below error
value cannot be resolved or is not a field
Please help!

Comment: On which field, the error is highlighted? If it is on `context.JobName`, then kindly check whether you have declared the `JobName` context variable in `Contexts` Tab.