# Running Talend jobs based on the date

Tags: talend

I have a talend job which takes the input from a csv file. The CSV file has child job names, and a start date. Right now this is how the job is built
I have a tFileInputDelimited, which takes the input from the file and this connects to the tFlowToIterate, which has the key value pairs

Example :

- c1, c2 and c3 which are C1 -->Job1
- C2 -->J1
- C3 -->1/16/2017

J1 is the name of the child job and C3 has the date.
In the trunjob I have used the "Use Dynamic job" and the Context job is "globalMap.get("c2") which will execute all the child jobs.

Now I need to execute those child jobs whose c3 value is today.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? what did you try, what didn't work ?

Comment: Right now I have a parent job which executes the child jobs. In the Context job of the trunjob, I have the code globalMap.get("c2"), where c2 has the job names. Similarly c3 has the start date associated with each job and only if the date is today's date, then the sub job should get executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are question is continuation of this thread [Running Talend child jobs through a parent job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633131/running-talend-child-jobs-through-a-parent-job/41635839?noredirect=1#comment70519640_41635839), then you can follow below steps,

Below is my input date

```
ChildJob1, 1/16/2017
ChildJob2, 1/17/2017
ChildJob3, 1/17/2017
```

I have modified the same job from previous answer with addition `tjava` component like below,

[image]

Below is the code that exist inside `tjava` component

```
System.out.println("|-----------------Date from Input file is "+row5.Date.toString()+"------------|");
System.out.println("|-----------------Job name from Input file is "+context.JobName+"---------------------------|");

String input = TalendDate.getDate("DD/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");
Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input); // Getting Today's date in DD/MM/YYYY format
 
context.IsTodayJob = TalendDate.compareDate(date,row5.Date) == 0 ? true : false;
```

In `tjava` component, I am setting the context variable `IsTodayJob` value by comparing Today's date and the date value from input file.

And I have connected the `tjava` component with `tRunJob` component through `run if` option with below condition

[image]

This gave me below result.

[image]

Hope this would help you out.